# Problems with deleting a copied directory in linux

Tags: linux

ok so i used "$ sudo cp -r" and now I cant delete the copied directory.
When I used rm -r it asked me if I wanted to "remove write-protected directory" and when I type "y" it says permission denied.

Comment: You will need to use sudo again. Also put -f flag to avoid confirmation

Answer (score 1):

Since you've copied the file with superuser privilege, you'll need superusers privilege to delete the file
Try the

```
 $sudo rm -r "filename"
```

so that the file gets deleted

If you want to eliminate *"remove write-protected directory"* these kind of messages (reporting it is write-protected) you can use -f option with it as @klashxx said. **f means forcefully**. ie;

```
 $sudo rm -rf "filename"
```

**r** stands for recursively deletion,(also delete files within the directory ,used for deleting folders )

**f** stands for forcefully